# Major annoyance of internet access (Wi-Fi router keeps failing, possible loop or routing issue)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I am having a peculiar problem wherein my Wi-Fi connection goes down erratically. Here is my network

- IP range: 192.168.0.0/24
- Network Wi-Fi Router: Netgear R7000 running latest firmware.
- DHCP Source: Wi-Fi Router (router is configured to give 50 IPs from 192.168.0.0-254)
- MAC address bending: Yes
- MAC address filtering (for Wi-Fi access): NO
- QoS: No
- Guest Network: No
- Wi-Fi sharing of devices directly connected via the Wi-Fi router (ReadySHARE): No
- DNS Source: Raspberry Pi running Pi-Hole & unbound over Ubuntu
- Wireless Clients: 20+ (including 6 Raspberry Pis)
- Wired Clients: 4 (NAS uses 2 ports and 2 ports are used by a Dell workstation running ESXi hosting 10 VMs)
  My Raspberry Pi's run Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS. I have microk8s installed on them. IP range on the Raspberry Pi is 192.168.0.0/24, but microk8s has its virtual network running (container interface) on 10.1.3.0 and docker has a virtual interface 172.17.0.1

When the network goes down I am unable to ping to an IP also (which means it isn’t a DNS resolution problem).

However, something funny happened and when I was trying to ping 8.8.8.8 from a laptop connected wirelessly having 192.168.x.x IP –

1. I got one reply from: 10.230.0.1 (Reply from 10.230.0.1: Destination net unreachable). When I ping the IP, I can get a reply and tracert shows it being one hop away –
2. My machine – Wi-Fi router – 10.230.0.1. I tried this from one of the Raspberry Pi’s and I got a reply too.
   I am not sure what this IP is or being used by. I rebooted my router and while my internet still isn’t working, I am unable to ping the IP.

**I get frequent disconnection when someone enters the home (new wireless device successfully attaching). Plus this unknown IP.**

I would deeply appreciate help in resolving this given that it is affecting my studies and job both ☹.

Do let me know if there are any diagnostics steps / information you need to assist.

PS: I have PCAP of tracert / ping to the IP 10.230.0.1 if it helps.

Update - 1

Tracert to google.com

```
tracert google.com

Tracing route to google.com [172.217.26.238]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     8 ms     8 ms     8 ms  10.230.0.1
  3     9 ms     8 ms     7 ms  125.99.88.145
  4     7 ms     9 ms     8 ms  203.212.193.30
  5     7 ms     8 ms     9 ms  125.99.55.254
  6     9 ms     8 ms     8 ms  125.99.55.253
  7     9 ms    10 ms     9 ms  136.232.27.245.static.jio.com [136.232.27.245]
  8    10 ms    14 ms    11 ms  74.125.51.62
  9     9 ms    10 ms    10 ms  209.85.245.197
 10     9 ms    15 ms    10 ms  216.239.51.197
 11    10 ms     9 ms     9 ms  bom05s09-in-f14.1e100.net [172.217.26.238]

Trace complete.
```

Comment: What is your public IP address when you internet is working? Can you provide a tracert to say google.com when your internet is working?

Comment: I've updated the post with the required details. The IP I'm referring to is part of the tracert :|

Comment: You haven't included your public IP address. 10.230.0.1 probably belongs to your ISP.